# Ruby callback when any module is included

Tags: ruby, module, callback, mixins

I know that we can define the `included` callback for any individual module.

Is there any way to define a callback that is invoked whenever *any* module gets included in another module or class? The callback would then preferably have access to both the module included, and the class/module where it is included.

Comment: `included` callback is what you want, I don't understand what's your confusion

Comment: @Tsao, it's not so cut-and-dried. If class `C` includes module `M` and `M` uses `included` to include `M` in another class `D` (`D.include(M)`), `M`'s  callback `included` that will cause `M` to be included into `D` a second time, then a third time, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot think or find a builtin way in Ruby to do it.

One alternative would be to monkey patch the `Module` class directly to create the callback. To do it we can add some wrapper methods around the original methods `include` and `extend` to force the execution of our defined callbacks each time the `include` or `extend` methods are called.

Something along the following lines should work:

```
class Module

  def self.before
    m_include = instance_method(:include)
    m_extend = instance_method(:extend)

    define_method(:include) do |*args, &block|
      included_callback(args[0])
      m_include.bind(self).call(*args, &block)
    end

    define_method(:extend) do |*args, &block|
      extend_callback(args[0])
      m_extend.bind(self).call(*args, &block)
    end
  end

  def included_callback(mod_name)
    puts "#{self} now has included Module #{mod_name}"
  end

  def extend_callback(mod_name)
    puts "#{self} now has extended Module #{mod_name}"
  end

  before
end
```

An example to test that it works:

```
module Awesome

  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end

  def self.baz
    puts "baz"
  end
end

class TestIncludeAwesome
  include Awesome
end

class TestExtendAwesome
  extend Awesome
end
```

The example code should print as output the following:

```
> TestIncludeAwesome now has included Module Awesome
> TestExtendAwesome now has extended Module Awesome
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like just what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
class D
  def self.callback(mod)
    include mod
  end
end

module M
  def hello
    puts 'hi'
  end

  def self.included(klass)
    D.callback(self) unless klass == D
  end
end

class C
  include M
end

C.new.hello #=> 'hi'
D.new.hello #=> 'hi'
```

When `C` includes `M`, `M::included` is executed with `klass#=>C`. Since `klass == D` is `false`, `D.callback(M)` is executed. `callback` includes `M` in class `D`, then `M::included` is executed with `klass#=>D`. Since `klass == D` is now true, `M` is not included into `D` a second time.